# jQuery .extend not interpolating a config value. why?

Tags: jquery

I have something simple I believe, yet I am getting js error.

```
 $.extend(hashONE,{options.item1 : options.item2});
```

also tried:

```
 $.extend(hashONE,{options[item1] : options[item2]});
```

also

```
 var opt = {options[item1] : options[item2]};
 $.extend(hashONE, opt);
```

All these generate an error on the "."

I must be daft, this is suppose to be easy :-)

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to do with the `options[item1]` as property name. Usually when making objects it is something like this `{key : "value"}`. I suspect your error is there rather than in the `$.extend()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a variable as a keyname using that syntax.

```
var opt = {};
opt[ options[ item1 ] ] = options[item2]
$.extend(hashONE, opt);
```

Also

```
var opt = {};
opt[ options.item1 ] = options.item2
$.extend(hashONE, opt);
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't want to go down this road as it seems that extend should take the values. But thank you for your answer. Accepted.

Comment: Yeah as the comment above from ced-b said, it wasn't an `$.extend` issue.. just JS.